# Document just vanished

Tags: files

I was preparing a text with LyX which I am sure as my name that I saved it on desktop. A few moments later, I decided to put it and some other related .lyx files into folder on desktop.

At the moment, the file just vanished. It is not in the folder, nor on the desktop. It does not occur in recent documents in LyX nor in Ubuntu menu.

What is happening???

Comment: Can you open it again from within LyX? (the menu is File > Open recent)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will find it for you or not but you could try this from a terminal:
    sudo find ~/ -name (whatever your file name is using * as wildcards)
    So if you think file name is abcd.txt but were not sure about the abcd:
    sudo find ~/ -name *.txt

Comment: Thank you for injecting some common sense to me. :D I might as well forget my name. The file turned out to be on home folder, not on desktop. I panicked very hard since it was a mighty part of my thesis... Thank you again!

Comment: lol. that's funny